# CKAN won't start

Tags: python, postgresql, solr, freebsd, ckan

On my FreeBSD 10, I managed to install PostgreSQL, Apache Solr and CKAN but when I run `paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini` I get these error messages (I know there is an issue with CKAN because on my ip:5000 I have a `error: connection failed`).

Here are the error messages:

```
$ paster serve /etc/ckan/default/production.ini 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 284, in command
    relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 321, in loadapp
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py", line 58, in make_app
    load_environment(conf, app_conf)
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 232, in load_environment
    p.load_all(config)
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 134, in load_all
    load(*plugins)
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 170, in load
    plugins_update()
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 116, in plugins_update
    environment.update_config()
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 357, in update_config
    plugin.configure(config)
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py", line 115, in configure
    self._check_urls_and_permissions()
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py", line 159, in _check_urls_and_permissions
    self._log_or_raise('The read-only user has write privileges.')
  File "/root/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py", line 140, in _log_or_raise
    raise DatastoreException(message)
ckanext.datastore.plugin.DatastoreException: The read-only user has write privileges.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your read-only postgresql user for the datastore database is not setup correctly: the user has write privileges. The relevant part of the docs is: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#set-permissions

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the problem like this....I have deleted the user "datastore_default" from the postgres. For Deleting the Postgres User Please refer: [Postgres Delete user](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-dropuser.html)

And create again the postgres user "datastore_default" as per the CKAN  Documentation. Please ref: [Create User datastore_default for CKAN](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#create-users-and-databases)